# Using AWS SDK (S3.putObject) to upload a Readable stream to S3 (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, stream

My goal is to upload a `Readable` stream to S3.

The problem is that AWS api seems to accept only a `ReadStream` as a stream argument.

For instance, the following snippet works just fine:

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./file.txt") // a ReadStream

await s3.putObject({
    Bucket: this.bucket,
    Key: this.key,
    Body: readStream,
    ACL: "bucket-owner-full-control"
}
```

Problem starts when I try to do the same with a `Readable` (`ReadStream` extends `stream.Readable`).

The following snippet fails

```
const { Readable } = require("stream")
const readable = Readable.from("data data data data") // a Readable

await s3.putObject({
    Bucket: this.bucket,
    Key: this.key,
    Body: readable,
    ACL: "bucket-owner-full-control"
}
```

the error I get from AWS sdk is: `NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented`

*** Note that I prefer a `Readable` rather than a `ReadStream` since I'd like to allow passing streams that are not necessarily originated from a file - an in-memory string for instance.
So a possible solution could be converting a `Readable` to a `Readstream` to work with the SDK.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you happen to search for that exact error text? There seems to be a number of similar question that provide possible solutions. Part of the issue is that a string of `data data data data` is not a file and a readable stream from that does not have any kind of metadata about its `ContentType` or similar.

Comment: Just tried to add a `ContentType ='STRING_VALUE'` but get the same behavior. According to the docs, the putObject method gets `Readable` `ReadableStream` `Blob` `string` `Uint8Array` or `Buffer` as body

Comment: ContentType according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) is defined as "A standard MIME type describing the format of the object data.". Which is defined by [w3 standards](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17). This would be values such as `text/csv` or `text/plain` for example. `putObject` cannot infer if the string of `data data data data` is a text file or csv file or similar.

Comment: The `STRING_VALUE` was taken from one of their examples. Anyway, just tryied `text/csv` and got the same :/

Comment: It's not clear what else you have tried, but the header comes from also content length not being present. Try adding `ContentLength` as well.

Comment: That works! Just needed to add the `ContentLength` to the request. Thank you so much @AlexanderStaroselsky. Would you like to add your solution as an answer or should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the `Readable` is no longer a file that has metadata such as MIME type and content length you'd need to update your `putObject` to include those values:

```js
const { Readable } = require("stream")
const readable = Readable.from("data data data data") // a Readable

await s3.putObject({
    Bucket: this.bucket,
    Key: this.key,
    Body: readable,
    ACL: "bucket-owner-full-control",
    ContentType: "text/plain",
    ContentLength: 42 // calculate length of buffer
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Example with length calculated and using Buffer:

```
import { Readable } from "stream";

  saveCreativeImage(name: string, image: Buffer): Promise<string> {
    const options: PutObjectRequest = {
      ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control',
      Bucket: EnvConfig.S3_CREATIVES_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: name,
      Body:  Readable.from(image),
      ContentType: 'image/png',
      ContentLength: image.length
    };
```

Note you used to be able to send Buffer directly but now I think a StreamingBlobTypes is required. Which is defined here:
https://github.com/awslabs/smithy-typescript/blob/21ee16a06dddf813374ba88728c68d53c3674ae7/packages/types/src/streaming-payload/streaming-blob-common-types.ts#L22

I think this was changed here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/commit/96938415e65ccc4353be8f816e919215de12a1b7#diff-252b2f214c37b3c487fd068bff4968eaa1c8a6085dc9eba0d7bfe15239b05094